# How to "sort" point list so it makes up a convex polygon?

Tags: python

Assuming I have the following:

A point is represented by a longitude latitude pair like this:

```
pointX = [-97.45454, 43.64545]
```

Assuming I had a list of points that made up a polygon:

```
testlist = [<pointA>, <pointC>, <pointE>, <pointB>]
```

Notice how it is out of order. In python, how can I "sort" the testlist such that the points, if connected, form a polygon without any intersection?

Comment: A polygon is a plane figure, but points on a sphere are not, in general, in one plane. If you assume that your points are in a plane, then what you're looking for is the *convex hull* of those points. There are several algorithms for computing that.

Comment: I am assuming this is flat. Treat numbers as X Y